# How to plot the correlance in pdf file?

Tags: r

I'd like to check the correlation between two columns of my data and plot them into the pdf file. Can someone tell me how to do that ?

```
diff    abund_mean
 0   3444804.79
 1   847887.02
 2   93654.19
 0   721692.76
 2   382711.04
 1   428656.65
 1   120933.91
 0   157528.72
 1   159650.70
 0   124602.80
 0   90844.33
 2   501825.37
 1   270592.56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do You need also the plot or just the correlation coeff?
This gives to you the scatterplot with r^2:

```
pdf(file="myplot.pdf", width = 10, height =13) #create new pdf
plot(diff ~ abund_mean) #see data
abline(lm<- lm(diff ~ abund_mean)) #add regression to plot 
legend("topright", bty="n", legend=paste
("R2 is", format(summary(lm)$adj.r.squared, digits=4))) #print the regr. coeff. on plot
dev.off() #end of pdf creation
summary(lm) #see all the regression coefficients (F-statistic, RSE, etc.)
```

Comment: Adjusted r-squared is not the same as "correlation between two columns".

Comment: You are rigth. Maybe he should study the object "lm". I think Shaxi Liver just needs correlation coefficient and a significance value.

Comment: No idea why people downgrade my reputation.. Did I do something wrong? or it was just a stupid question ?

Comment: I don't know... @ShaxiLiver could you please post an image of your pdf when you'll make it?

Comment: Yeah, I will. At the moment I am trying to make an empty matrix and fill it with my data. I have not idea how to do that but I don't want to ask here because my rep would go a bit lower once again.